# Create a new list view when an item is created

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, list-view

Is there a way to have SharePoint Designer create a new list view via a workflow when a new item is added?

The view would be based off previous views, just updating the ID of the item in the filtering field.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine how many views will be there in a long run. Not sure why you need to create new view for every new item can you explain? 
But the better approach would be have a category column and create a view based on that field(you can select multiple column to group by or even can use [me]  to filter items only created by user)

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported to achieve your requirement via designer workflow OOB way.
Why do you want to create a new view each time a new item is created?
If the list contains 100 items, 100 list views will be created. It's crazy.
If you want to filter out items in list view, you can choose other column values instead of ID.